# Drop rows in pandas if records in two columns do not appear together at least twice in the dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am having a dataset with dates and company names. I only want to keep rows such that the combination of the company name and the date appeared in the dataset at least twice.

To illustrate the problem, let us assume I have the following dataframe:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['28/02/2017', 'Apple'], ['28/02/2017', 'Apple'], ['31/03/2017', 'Apple'],['28/02/2017', 'IBM'],['28/02/2017', 'WalMart'],
['28/02/2017', 'WalMart'],['03/07/2017', 'WalMart']]), columns=['date','keyword'])
```

My desired output would be:

```py
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['28/02/2017', 'Apple'], ['28/02/2017', 'Apple'],
                             ['28/02/2017', 'WalMart'],
                             ['28/02/2017', 'WalMart']]), columns=['date', 'keyword'])
```

I would know how to drop the rows based on conditions in two columns, but I can't figure out how to drop rows based on how many times the combination of two values appeared in a dataset.

Could anyone provide some insight?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) with specify columns for check dupes and `keep=False` for return all dupe rows by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df2 = df1[df1.duplicated(subset=['date','keyword'], keep=False)]
print (df2)
         date  keyword
0  28/02/2017    Apple
1  28/02/2017    Apple
4  28/02/2017  WalMart
5  28/02/2017  WalMart
```

If need specify number of rows use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with count by [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
df2 = df1[df1.groupby(['date','keyword'])['date'].transform('size') >= 2]
```

If small DataFrame or performance is not important use [filter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#filtration):

```
df2 = df1.groupby(['date','keyword']).filter(lambda x: len(x) >= 2)
print (df2)
         date  keyword
0  28/02/2017    Apple
1  28/02/2017    Apple
4  28/02/2017  WalMart
5  28/02/2017  WalMart
```

Answer (score 3):

```
df1.groupby(['date','keyword']).apply(lambda x: x if len(x) >= 2 else None).dropna()
```

**Output**

```
         date  keyword
0  28/02/2017    Apple
1  28/02/2017    Apple
4  28/02/2017  WalMart
5  28/02/2017  WalMart
```

Comment: You don't need the `if` within your `lambda` - it should suffice to just do `lambda x: len(x) >= 2)`

Comment: @asongtoruin thanks for the feedback, however if i go by your it gives series back with multi index, not sure how to proceed, help would be appreciated here..will have to use something like filter here